# javascript get text at mose postion

Tags: javascript, onmousemove

How can I get text at mouse position?
I have now some like this

```
document.body.onmousemove = function(){
    //todo:Get text at mouse position
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by text? Do you mean a single character, a word, a block of text in some container? Depending on which you mean this could be very easy or very hard

Comment: Hi Shaunwithanau.
 thx for your rapid answer. The idea is to get a single word , at mouse position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
One way of doing so is using [PrototypeJs][1]

Try this one let me know if there is any problem

$(document.body).observe('click', respondToClick);

function respondToClick(event) {
  var element = event.element();
  var source = element.innerHTML;
}
```